# How can I set my desired folder options for "Music" folders permanently in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows

When I open a folder that contains music files Windows shows me name, #, title, contributing artists and album. I don't want # nor title (name is good enough for me). I also want Length to show up. I can change each folder as I come to it but I would like to change any newly created music type folder to show only the fields I want. By now Windows should be able to do this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/how-to-adjust-the-default-column-displays-in/dbba21bd-e8e3-4dd2-be54-f419de6656f0):

This method works on Windows 8. I've just tested it. I've edited a bit to match the UI of Win8, otherwise, everything is the same as in the above link.

Make sure you have set the type of your folder as a `Music` type folder (by going to the Home tab on the ribbon > Properties > Customize > *Optimize this folder for: Music*

> Open the Registry Editor (by swiping from the right, clicking search, typing `regedit`)
>   Go to the following keys:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]`

> and

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]`

> Right-click on the Bags key in the left pane and select Delete, then do the same thing for BagMRU.
>
> This will remove most existing customizations for things like window sizes, positions and views. >While still in the same place in the Registry Editor, you will need to manually recreate one of >these keys with a new setting. Right-click on the following key in the left pane:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell]`

> Create a new key called `Bags` to replace the one you just deleted. Right-click on `Bags`, select >New>Key and name this new key `AllFolders`. Right-click on `AllFolders`, select New>Key and name >this new key `Shell`. The end result should look like this:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]`

> Now left-click on the last `Shell` key and in the right pane right-click in an empty area and select New>String Value. Name this new string `FolderType` and once created, double-click on it and in the Value Data box you can set the default view which all folders will initially take (unless otherwise specified) by entering one of the following values:

NotSpecified

Contacts

Documents

Music

Pictures

> For example if you enter `Documents` in the `FolderType` Value Data box (which I recommend), then all folders for which you do not manually set a view will default to the standard Documents folder view as you set it.
>
> Now in Windows Explorer go to your \Users[username]\ directory and for each of the main folder types under there (Documents, Pictures, Music, Videos), make sure that you set the view you wish, including things like choosing which columns to show and how wide they each are, the size of any icons/thumbnails, the way in which they are sorted, etc. As you make the changes, for each folder click the View tab in the ribbon at the top of Windows Explorer > Options > Change Folder and Search Options. Go to the View tab and click the 'Apply to Folders' button. This will set this view for all folders of that same type, and this method also means that should you copy files of any other type into a folder, it will not alter that folder's view settings - from now on the settings should remain exactly as you leave them.
>
> Go to the following key:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell]`

> Left-click on the `Shell` key and in the right pane, if you can see  `BagMRU Size` then there is no need to undertake this step. If it isn't there however, right-click and select New>DWORD 32-bit Value and name it `BagMRU Size`. Now set this value to `10000` in Decimal view.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, in your music folder as you say just right click on sort by and then in the bottom you'd see more and from there you can remove # and add anything you wish like date and stuff.